# Trying to make a custom changeable background

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a changeable background with a button and menu like on the new tab page that google has can you help

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the button click by setting an event listener to it

btn stands for the variable referencing the button element. It's just a personal preference, you can name the variable your choice.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // code to be executed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have the button click set the class to the body tag.